# Manual startup services in Windows 10 are running after bootup

Tags: windows-10, boot, windows-services

I have two services in my Windows 10 PC. These are set as "manual" startup because they are a webserver and a database and I don't want to start them if I don't want to develope.

I found that sometimes they are running when windows starts other times I have to manual startup. Why I found them running? Is windows 10 managing something like a fast shutdown-bootup? Consider that I always use "Shutdown" buttun and I never use standby, hibernate or suspend.

Comment: The default in Windows 10 is to treat "Shut Down" as "Hibernate".

Comment: Really??? Can I avoid this or force a service to -really- shutdown when I power off the PC?

Comment: Yes, just follow [these instructions](https://windowsten.info/tutorials/5767-how-to-fully-shut-down-windows-10) to disable fast restart (which is equivalent to hibernate). If it's not already enabled, you may want to show **Hibernate** in the shut-down menu, so you still have the option.

Comment: Manual startup services can be started "automatically" (ie at boot time) if other services depend on them. Dependencies are set up in the various services' subkeys in the registry.

Comment: Manual startup services are started "automatically" (ie at boot time) if other services that are set for automatic start depend on them. e.g. if service A is automatic, B is manual, and A depends on B, then when the Service Manager decides "oh, I should start A", it finds that A needs B, so it starts B first. In effect B gets "promoted" to automatic start.  Dependencies are set up in the various services' subkeys in the registry, with the DependOnService value. You may also see DependOnGroup but this doesn't "promote" anything and is commonly only used for kernel drivers (Type < 0x10).

Comment: These services had no dependencies, can you confirm that a manual started service doesn't stop in fastboot restart?

Answer (score 0):

Use a Script to shut down your computer, you have a few options:

```
shutdown.exe /s /f /t 0 /d p:2:4
```

this shuts down the PC the old way without fast boot which is now the default when using the GUI. This makes booting slower.

Keeping fast boot, you can stop your services first and then shut down the Windows 10 way:

```
net stop webService
net stop databaseService
shutdown.exe  /s /f /t 0 /hybrid /d p:2:4
```

notice the `/hybrid` switch for the shutdown command, this is for using fast boot.